# Redirect domain to subfolder

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, webserver

I have a domain name mydomain.com, but I want to redirect its traffic to mydomain.com/~myname/ on Apache 2.2. I tried to write redirect rule but it doesn't seem working. It's because when I access to mydomain.com from outside of LAN, I do not have a permission to access /. "index.html" is set up at /Users/myname/ which is DocumentRoot of web. How can I redirect a traffic or properly set up so that a user will see index.html in /Users/myname/ when they type mydomain.org?

Thanks

Comment: It may be helpful to know what you tried exactly, i.e. post the exact file and contents of the redirect rule you mention.

Comment: Looks somewhat similar to [How to point subdomain and subdirectory to another host](http://superuser.com/q/606823/150988) (which, unfortunately, doesn’t have any answers).